# How to setup TPU parallelism/FSDP with HuggingFace Transformers

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tpu

I've been trying to fine-tune a model using TPU parallelism / FSDP with a Kaggle TPU notebook. The reason I need to set up FSDP is because the model I'm using is very large (Openlm's open llama 3b v2). When I try to fine-tune it, I quickly run out of memory on the TPU.

Here's my code:

[Link to Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u9DLBPRn-spLAkjHpjtMTUpSIqcq1ks1)

```
!pip install sentencepiece
!pip install -U accelerate
!pip install -U transformers
!pip install cloud-tpu-client
!pip install torch-xla
!pip install pyarrow

import torch
import torch_xla
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, Trainer, TrainingArguments
import pandas as pd
import accelerate
from accelerate import Accelerator, DistributedType
import numpy as np
import pyarrow
import os
import logging
from transformers import logging as hf_logging

# Set the environment variables for TPU and the number of processes
os.environ["ACCELERATE_DEVICE_PLACEMENT"] = "TPU"
os.environ["ACCELERATE_NUM_PROCESSES"] = "8"

# Set the device to TPU
device = xm.xla_device()

MODEL_PATH = "openlm-research/open_llama_3b_v2"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH, use_fast=True)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH).to(device)

# Set configurable variables
output_dir = "/kaggle/working/"  # Directory to save the fine-tuned model
num_train_epochs = 25  # Number of training epochs
per_device_train_batch_size = 32  # Batch size for training
per_device_eval_batch_size = 32  # Batch size for evaluation
warmup_ratio = 0.1  # Ratio of total training steps for warmup steps
logging_steps = 50  # Ratio of total training steps for logging steps
save_ratio = 0.5  # Ratio of total training steps for save steps
evaluation_strategy = "epoch"  # Evaluation strategy (e.g., "steps", "epoch", "no")
weight_decay = 0.01  # Weight decay for the optimizer
max_len = 650

# Load data from parquet file
data = pd.read_parquet("/kaggle/input/train-input/ready_to_train.parquet")

data = data.dropna(subset=["combined"])
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["combined"])

# Split data into train and test sets
train_data = data.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)
test_data = data.drop(train_data.index)

tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

# Tokenize train and test data
train_encodings = tokenizer(train_data["combined"].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=max_len)
test_encodings = tokenizer(test_data["combined"].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=max_len)

# Tokenize labels
train_labels_encodings = tokenizer(train_data["answer"].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=max_len)
test_labels_encodings = tokenizer(test_data["answer"].tolist(), truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=max_len)

# Create dataset class
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, label_encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.label_encodings = label_encodings

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        labels = torch.full_like(item["input_ids"], -100)  # Fill the tensor with -100 (ignore index)
        labels[0] = self.label_encodings["input_ids"][idx][0]  # Set the first position to the correct label
        item["labels"] = labels
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.label_encodings["input_ids"])

# Create train and test datasets
train_dataset = Dataset(train_encodings, train_labels_encodings)
test_dataset = Dataset(test_encodings, test_labels_encodings)

# Initialize the accelerator with the desired configuration
accelerator = Accelerator()

# Calculate total training steps
total_train_steps = len(train_dataset) // per_device_train_batch_size * num_train_epochs

# Calculate warmup_steps, logging_steps, save_steps, and eval_steps based on epoch
warmup_steps = int(total_train_steps * warmup_ratio)
eval_steps = len(train_dataset) // per_device_train_batch_size

# Set training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=per_device_eval_batch_size,
    warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
    weight_decay=weight_decay,
    logging_dir=output_dir,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    evaluation_strategy=evaluation_strategy,
    eval_steps=eval_steps,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    save_strategy="epoch",
    report_to="none",  # Set report_to to "none"
)

# Set the log level to logging.INFO
hf_logging.set_verbosity(logging.INFO)

# Create trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
)

# Fine-tune the model
trainer.train()

# Save the fine-tuned model
trainer.save_model(output_dir)
```

I've tried a bunch, lower the batch size (gets closer but not close enough, I can probably run it on a batch size of 1 but 2 was too much and I would rather use parallelism anyway.

I found [this link](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#pytorchxla-fully-sharded-data-parallel) which is from the HuggingFace transformers documentation, but I don't understand how it works.